# internal server error comes when .htaccess file is uploaded on my hosting server

Tags: php, .htaccess

My .htaccess file is working well in my local wamp server but i upload my site to hosting then .htaccess file giving internet server error...

### below is my .htaccess code...

```
php_value allow_url_fopen On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+).html?[demo]$ fixed.php?1=$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+).html?$ network-page.php?network=$1  [QSA,L]  
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ 2.php?1=$1&2=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$  network-page.php?network=$1&country=$2&category=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ sub-detail-page.php?network=$1&country=$2&category=$3&subcategory=$4  [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+).html?$ detail-page.php?network=$1&country=$2&category=$3&subcategory=$4&package_id=$5
```

---

Kindly tell me what is issue... 
because same .htaccess file is working in my local wamp server

Comment: check your logs

Comment: btw; this isn't a php question.

Comment: error_log is empty.. showing nothing ...

Answer (score 0):

Since it's working on your local wamp server but not on a remote server:

- a possible cause of error could be if the file permissions on the
  .htaccess file are not set correctly.
- When uploading your .htaccess files, it is very important you upload
  the file in 'ASCII' mode.

For more info on .htaccess try checking this [htaccess-guide](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/) and especially the [How to use](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/how-to-use-htaccess/) page.

Comment: If you still have some questions regarding this issue you might want to update the question or simply ask a new one. If your question is answered in a satisfied way you may want to accept and or upvote an answer. Good Luck